# $24ml+1=k^2$ has no solution for all $l=1 \dots m$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, quadratic-residues

Investigating solutions of $$24ml+1=k^2$$ for $l=1\dots m$

The question is to find the $m$-s for which the above equation has no solution for all $l=1..m$-s.
The first few $m$-s are:
$$3, 9, 24, 27, 81, 192, 243, 432, 729$$
Actually have found that the $m$ should be of form $2^a3^b$. Seems hang on the simple task, of finding general formula for this.

---

One interesting addition. Just tested the cases when the $$12ml+1=k^2$$ has no solution for all $$l=1..m$$ Seems it has no solution iff $m=3^a$ But has no proof yet.

Comment: Is it no solution for any $l$ in that range or some $l$ in the range?

Comment: for all $l$-s in the range $l=1..m$.

Comment: Who said there should be a formula?

Comment: @Ivan Neretin, Actually this is a good point. The reason why I think there should be a formula is that it is enough easy to prove that those values should be of form $2^a3^b$ because of $24=2^33^2$. And also we know about everythig related to quadratic residues.

Comment: The number $3$ in your list of $m$s does not appear in all rows of my final list below. Does this make my approach incorrect? How did you arrive at your list?

Comment: @poetasis $3$ appear in the list because $24*3*1+1$, $24*3*2+1$, $24*3*3+1$ are not squares. But $5$ does not appearin the list because $24*5*1+1$ is a square.

Comment: I know $3$ works for $l=1$ but it does not for $l\in\{,4,5\}$. and possible other l-values. That is why I asked the question. I thought your question was to find m-values that have yield no solutions where $1 \le l \le m$.

Comment: @poetasis actually the question is for the range $1 \le l \le m$. For the $m=3$ the $l=4$ and $l=5$ are not in the range.

Comment: I see. Now I need to edit the last part of my answer.

Comment: We know that the highly composite number have the form $2^\alpha3^\beta5^\gamma\dots$ wits $\alpha\geqslant\beta\geqslant\gamma\dots$, but where is the formula? Ditto for the super-abundant numbers. Then again, the terms of [A256758](https://oeis.org/A256758) are either primes or powers of 3, but where is the formula? Same thing here.

Comment: Search result with $m<100000.$  
$m=(3, 9, 24, 27, 81, 192, 243, 432, 729, 1536, 1944, 2187, 4608, 5184, 6561, 12288, 19683, 23328, 31104, 55296, 59049, 69984, 98304)$  
All solutions have the form $2^a3^b.$

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple of results that can be proved:

**There is no solution if $m=3^a, a>0.$**

For $24ml=(k-1)(k+1)$ we must have $k=6x\pm 1$. Then$$ml=\frac {x(3x\pm 1)}{2}.$$

Now if $m=3^a, a>0$, then $m$ has to be a factor of $x$. But then $l\ge \frac {3x- 1}{2}>m,$ a contradiction.

**There is a solution if $m$ is not divisible by $3$.**

Let $2m=3l\pm 1$. Then  $l\le m$ and
$$24lm+1=12l(3l\pm 1)+1=(6l\pm 1)^2.$$

Answer (score 3):

The OP also conjectures that $12ml+1=k^2$ has no solutions for $1\le l\le m$ if and only if $ m=3^a$. This is true and can be proved as follows.

**Only if**

For $12ml=(k-1)(k+1)$ we must have $k=6x\pm 1$. Then $ml=x(3x\pm 1).$

Let $m=3^aM$, where $M>1$ is coprime to $3$. Let $x=3^aX$ and then $$Ml=X(3^{a+1}X\pm 1).$$

We can choose $X$, $0< X <M$, such that $3^{a+1}X\equiv 1$ modulo $M$. Replacing $X$ by $M-X$ if necessary we can therefore choose $X$,  $0< X \le \frac{M}{2},$ such that $(3^{a+1}X\pm 1)=MY$ for some integer $Y$.
Then $l=XY$.

If $m<l$ then $$3^aM<\frac{M}{2}\frac{(3^{a+1}M\pm 2)}{2M}  \text{ i.e. }  3^a<\frac{3^{a+1}\pm \frac{2}{M}}{4}.  $$
Then $a=0$ and $M=2$. But then $l=1$ gives the solution $12ml+1=5^2$.

**If**

Let $m=3^a$ and $x=3^aX$,  then we must solve $l=X(3^{a+1}X\pm 1)>3^a=m,$ a contradiction.

Answer (score -2):

Under $100$ there are $84$ $m$-values yield no integer integers $(k)$ for $l=1$.

To find them is simple. $\quad k\not\in\mathbb{N} \text { for }k=\sqrt{24 m + 1)}$.

For example, for any non-zero integer $(m)$,
$$\text{If }\space \sqrt{24 m + 1)}\ne
\big\lfloor \sqrt{24 m + 1)}\space\big\rfloor 
\text{, then print } m \text{, endif }\tag{1}$$

This is the same as testing $\quad\sqrt{24 m \times(1) + 1)},\quad $
i.e. $l=1.\quad$ To find non-solution m-values for any other l-values, you must test the full $\quad 24m\times(l)+1, l\le m.\quad$ For examples,

\begin{align*}
\text{If }l=2,\quad& m\in\{ \emptyset \}\\
\text{If }l=3,\quad& m\in\{ 1,2,3\}\\
\text{If }l\in\{4,5,6,7,8\}\quad& m\in\{ \emptyset \}\\
\text{If }l=9,\quad& m\in\{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}\\
\text{If }l\in\{10,11,12,\cdots, 23\}\quad& m\in\{ \emptyset \}\\
\mathbf{\vdots}
\end{align*}
Your derived list is correct but I cannot offer a better formula for finding these m-values.

$\textbf{Update}\\$
We can solve for $l$ and see which k-values yield an integer for a given m-value.

$$l = \frac{k^2 - 1}{24 m} \quad\text{and we know }m\ne0\tag{2}$$

We can find $k^2$ by taking multiples of $24m$ and adding 1 to see if any $\sqrt{k^2}$ yields an integer. Having found $k$ we plug it back into equation $(2)$ and find $l$. We have a valid $m$ if and only if the smallest $l$ generated is greater than $m$. The test values for $m$ can quickly be obtained from equation $(1)$ above.

Comment: Not sure if I follow the idea. Could you please explain a bit?

Comment: Actually thank you for detailed description, but the question is finding the genereal solution for all $l=1..m$. My hint was that the general solution should be some kind of $2^a3^b$. We just need to clarify the $a$ and $b$ rules.

Comment: @Gevorg Hmayakyan I have edited my answer to show how things aren't so simple.